# Error in getting metadata from Geonetwork using API

Tags: api, geonetwork, cors, http-headers

I need to get metadata from the Geonetwork using Api for displaying the data in the grid but when I use to call api using XMLHttpRequest it throws me error with 403 forbidden CORS issue even I had allowed the cross-orign in the request, this is how I used my code

```js
const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/api/0.1/recordsfrom=1&hitsPerPage=10000';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', apiUrl);

var username = 'admin';
var password = 'admin';
var credentials = username + ':' + password;

xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(credentials));

xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/xml");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        let xmlDoc = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(xmlDoc);
    }
    else {
        console.log("^^^^^XHR Failed:" + apiUrl)
    }
};
xhr.send();
```